# EF CodeFirst Mapping relationship between derived classes to the same table

Tags: entity-framework, orm, ef-code-first, mapping

I need to do the following mapping

[image: Class diagram]
OrderItem will map to tbl_order_item

OrderItemCustomization will map to tbl_order_item_customization

I have a column [cd_order_item] in tbl_order_item_customization which is the foreign key

The problem is how I map the relationship between

CardOrderItem -> CardOrderItemCustomization

CustomCardOrderItem -> CustomCardOrderItemCustomization

I tried this

```
public class OrderItemConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<OrderItem>
{
  public OrderItemConfiguration()
  {
    ToTable("tbl_order_item");
    HasKey(i => i.Id);
    Property(i => i.Id).HasColumnName("cd_order_items");
    HasRequired(i => i.Order).WithMany(o => o.Items).Map(m => m.MapKey("cd_order"));
    HasRequired(i => i.Product).WithMany().Map(m => m.MapKey("cd_product"));
    Property(i => i.Quantity).HasColumnName("cd_quantity");
    Property(i => i.UnitAmount).HasColumnName("vl_item").HasColumnType("money");
    Property(i => i.TotalAmount).HasColumnName("vl_total").HasColumnType("money");
    Property(i => i.DiscountAmount).HasColumnName("vl_discount");
    Property(i => i.CostAmount).HasColumnName("vl_cost_price");
    Property(i => i.NetAmount).HasColumnName("vl_net");
    HasRequired(i => i.Status).WithMany().Map(m => m.MapKey("cd_status"));
    Property(i => i.IsActive).HasColumnName("fl_active");
  }
}

public class AbstractCardOrderItemConfiguration :   EntityTypeConfiguration<AbstractCardOrderItem>
{
  public AbstractCardOrderItemConfiguration()
  {
    Property(i => i.IsVirtual).HasColumnName("fl_virtual");
    Property(i => i.CardType).HasColumnName("cd_card_type").IsOptional();
    Property(i => i.Document).HasColumnName("nr_document");
    HasRequired(i => i.Package).WithRequiredPrincipal().Map(m =>   m.MapKey("cd_order_item_base"));
  }
}

public class CardOrderItemConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<CardOrderItem>
{
  public CardOrderItemConfiguration()
  {
    HasRequired(i => i.CardOrderItemCustomization).WithRequiredPrincipal().Map(m =>   m.MapKey("cd_order_items"));
  }
}

public class CustomCardOrderItemConfiguration :   EntityTypeConfiguration<CustomCardOrderItem>
{
  public CustomCardOrderItemConfiguration()
  {
    HasRequired(i =>   i.CardWithCustomPhotoOrderItemCustomization).WithRequiredPrincipal().Map(m =>   m.MapKey("cd_order_items"));
  }
}
```

But this gives me an error:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> cd_order_items: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique.
>   Property name 'cd_order_items' is already defined.

There is any way that can I achieve the desired mapping?